# coop_mission_haunted: Stuck in room with 4 skulls and a pillar

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Just tried playing this map today via the Steam Workshop.  When I first spawn, there's a small obelisk in the middle of the room with 4 glowing green skulls with a faint pillar of light that rises to the top of the room.

[image]

There are 4 doors that are wide open that lead to the outer courtyard, presumably.

[image]

When approaching those doors, they close automatically and will not open until I reach a far away distance.

[image]

How can I get out of this room? No enemies have spawned yet and there seems to be no way to trigger enemy spawns or anything else of the sort.

Comment: I've never played the missions, nor do I have the new operation, but have you tried looking at the middle of the room and walking backwards ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Watch the first part of [this guys](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC1hlBVlxLDY--Ih2fEyH5nQ) YouTube video from around 2 minutes onwards:

[coop_mission_haunted CS GO - Counter-Strike Gameplay](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF9pJOHdX7Y)

Being that it's a coop mission, you need to do it with another player, that seems like the only way to open the doors.

Team-work makes the dream work.